# Plotting a comet like animation for multiple variables

Tags: matlab, animation, graph, data-visualization

I am trying to code a visualization with 4 variables ( Carbon emission, Energy consumption,  population and year)

The data set i have collected so far looks like this

With C1990 representing Carbon emission data 1990 and so on.
[image]

I have seen an online visualization whereby he uses some sort of animation which i suspect is comet3.

His visualization looks like something below that i have recreated using paint. The animation will change in accordance to the year, the circle representing the countries and the size of the circle represent the carbon emission. Basically the circle will move and scale accordingly from year 1990 to 2010.

I have been checking up on online resources but was unable to find something similar with a snipe code as sample. I am pretty new to matlab thus i am wondering if anyone here is able to get me off with a sample or guide me along ?

[image]

Comment: Did you already manage to plot one year?

Comment: @Daniel No. Unfortunately i am pretty lost as to how to began.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to implement this in Matlab; but you might be thinking of [Trendalyzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trendalyzer), developed by Hans Rosling's [GapMinder Foundation](http://www.gapminder.org/). Quote:

> Trendalyzer is an information visualization software for animation of statistics that was initially developed by Hans Rosling's Gapminder Foundation in Sweden. In March 2007 it was acquired by Google Inc. The current beta version is a Flash application that is preloaded with statistical and historical data about the development of the countries of the world [...] Components of the Trendalyzer software, particularly the Flash-based Motion Chart gadget, have become available for public use as part of the Google Visualizations API.

You might also want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018026/producing-an-animated-comet-plot-in-r?rq=1) question.